# Not able to update anaconda -Error Corrupted Environment

Tags: python, anaconda

while trying to update the anaconda. I am getting the following error.
I tried to update also, its not working.
How to fix this python error.

CorruptedEnvironmentError: The target environment has been corrupted. Corrupted environments most commonly
occur when the conda process is force-terminated while in an unlink-link
transaction.
  environment location: D:\vivek\Learning\Anaconda
  corrupted file: D:\vivek\Learning\Anaconda\conda-meta\python-3.7.1-h33f27b4_4.json

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps below:

> 1. Remove all the packages that are corrupt.
> 2. Try to install them again(only using conda).
> 3. Update your Conda and python if needed.
> 4. Try again with different versions if needed.
>
> Extra step: If you have a new conda environment and you find the error is because of some installing issues then try installing Conda again.

This will fix all the errors